# Yii2 login by otp does not make a cookie

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, one-time-password

I use Yii2-advanced-app(2.0.15) and i need to do the logon operation with OTP.
With the cell number and password, everything is correct and the cookie is correct but when I use an opt, no value is created for the cookie.

My ajax code:

```
$("#m-sendCode__form-submit").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled','true');
    let mobile = $('#mobile').val();
    let csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
    let rememberMe = $("#remember2").prop('checked');
    // console.log(rememberMe);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/loginbysms',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            _csrfFrontend: csrfToken,
            phone: phone,
            rememberMe: rememberMe
        },
        timeout: 6000
    })
    .done(function(data) {
            let response = JSON.parse(data);
            // console.log(data);
            if (response.sent === 1){
                 $.ajax({
                        url: '/loginbysms',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            _csrfFrontend: csrfToken,
                            verify: verify,
                            // rememberMe: rememberMe
                        },
                    })
                   .done(function(data) {
                        let s = JSON.parse(data);
                        if (s.status === 1){
                            window.location.href = '/';
                        } 
                    });
            }
     })
     .fail(function(error)){
            console.log(error);
     });
});
```

And my controller is:

```
public function actionLoginbysms()
{
    $dataAjax = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $session = Yii::$app->session;


    if(isset($dataAjax)) {
        if (isset($dataAjax['phone']) && !empty($dataAjax['phone'])) {
              $phone = $dataAjax['phone'];
              $user = User::findByPhone2($phone);
              $sendSMS = new SendSMS();
              if ($sendSMS->SendSMS($user->user_otp, $phone)) {
                   echo json_encode(['sent' => 1]);
                   exit;
              } else {
                   echo json_encode(['sent' => 0]);
                   exit;
              }
        }
        if(isset($dataAjax['verify]) && !empty($dataAjax['verfy'])){
              $authorizedUser = User::findByOtp($session- 
                 >get('user_phone'), $dataAjax['verify']);
              if (isset($authorizedUser) && !empty($authorizedUser)) {
                     Yii::$app->user->login($authorizedUser, 3600 * 24 * 
                     30)
                     echo json_encode(['status' => 1]);
                     exit;
              }
        }
    }

}
```

When everything is true and the code is sent correctly by the user, the user enters the home page correctly but no value for the cookie is saved.

Please tell me the mistake.

Comment: Do not use `exit` - it will break framework flow and some operations may not be performed correctly (like sending headers, including cookies). You should return response, preferably using [`asJson()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-controller#asJson()-detail).

Comment: @rob006 thanks, you're right,  it was precisely my mistake in this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller should be changed as follows:

```
public function actionLoginbysms()
{

    $dataAjax = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $session = Yii::$app->session;

    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        if (isset($dataAjax['phone']) && !empty($dataAjax['phone'])) {

            $mobile = $dataAjax['phone'];
            $user = User::findByPhone2($phone);

            if ($user) {
                unset($dataAjax['phone']);
                $numbers = range(10000, 99999);
                shuffle($numbers);
                $session->set('user_phone', $phone);

                if (isset($dataAjax['rememberMe']) && !empty($dataAjax['rememberMe'])
                    && ($dataAjax['rememberMe'] == true)) {
                    $session->set('rememberMe', 'yes');
                    unset($dataAjax['rememberMe']);
                }

                $user->user_otp = $numbers[0];
                $user->save();

                try {
                    $sendSMS = new SendSMS();
                    $sendSMS->SendSMS($user->user_otp, $phone);
                } catch (\Throwable $e) {
                    return [
                        'sent' => 0
                    ];
                }

                return [
                    'sent' => 1
                ];

            } else {
                return ['user_not_found' => 1];
            }
        }
        else if (isset($dataAjax['verify']) && !empty($dataAjax['verify'])) {
            if ($session->isActive && $session->has('user_phone')) {
                $authorizedUser = User::findByOtp($session->get('user_phone'), $dataAjax['verify']);

                if (isset($authorizedUser) && !empty($authorizedUser)) {
                    unset($dataAjax['verify']);
                    $session->remove('user_phone');
                    $authorizedUser->user_otp = '';
                    $authorizedUser->save();

                    if(Yii::$app->user->login($authorizedUser, 3600 * 24 * 30)) {
                        return ['authenticationSuccess' => 1];
                    }
                }
            }

            return ['authenticationSuccess' => 0];
        }
    }
}
```

As @rob006 said, we should not use **exit**.

With the help of **Yii::@app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON**, everything works fine